# How to intelligently change signature of function in the scope of the project?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, ide, jetbrains-ide

I want to change the signature of a function in the Python module, which has been used many times in the current project.

If you use the refactoring feature of IDEA (with Python plug-in), changing the function name can take effect within the scope of the whole project; but changing the signature can't, and don't see this option of scope.

Go to Google to search the relevant content, did not find more useful information.

Does IDEA really have no way to intelligently change the signature of functions in the whole project scope?

If the answer is No, are there any other solutions?

Note: Of course, regular expressions can also be used. This option is already known.

Comment: Well, that `Refactor | Change Signature` action **should** do the job here. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/change-signature.html E.g. IDEA with PHP Plugin: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/refactoring-php.html#php_change_signature. PyCharm: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/change-signature.html **P.S.** Cannot speak about Python/IDEA .. but it works fine in actual PhpStorm.

Comment: @LazyOne This is known. On the right-click menu, after renaming, the key point is "whole project".From the hyperlink you sent, it seems that there is no such option. Is it the whole project by default?

Comment: @Andy Yes, all usages of the function in the project should be refactored by Change Signature.

Comment: @LazyOne I'm sure that's not the case in IDEA for Python or PyCharm. Maybe it doesn't have this feature.

Comment: @Andy So what is the scope where it **does** change the signature for you? Module only? Or perhaps it does not do even that?

Comment: @LazyOne It seems that only the current file has been changed.

Comment: @Andy Maybe that function is not used anywhere? Or IDE does not see any references (e.g. some dynamic code where IDE is unable to resolve such reference). Does it show function usage places when you use `Find Usages` on it? If not -- please try `File | Invalidate Caches`, restart IDE and let it re-index your project.

Comment: @LazyOne  It turns out that the problem has been successfully solved after the operation according to the method you said! thank you! By the way, how to deal with this post at present? Close it and delete it?I'm a StackOverFlow rookie and don't know much about it.

Comment: @Andy Post your own answer with your solution and accept it later (e.g. few hours later / next day) -- this will help other users in a similar situation and having Accepted Answer will make it more visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set the range like renaming, it's not quite clear what the exact range is, but it's definitely not limited to the current file.

If it only takes effect in the current file, then the correct parsing relationship is probably not established, then you should `Find Usages` ( Control+left mouse button is the default shortcut), check it, and if you find any errors, can use `File | Invalidate Caches` to try to clear the cache and restart IDE.

Thanks LazyOne.